# How to access a static file in controller in turbogears

Tags: python, turbogears, turbogears2

I have an XML file in /my_project/public/xml/file.xml, that I want to read and parse it in one method in controller. The file can be easily accessed through a template, but I have no experience with accessing files in controller.

Answer (score 0):

the more simple I know : 
jest get the diname of base of the project
`filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(myproject.__file__), 'public', 'xml', 'file.xml')`